# How to add null value to List generator element?

Tags: arrays, list, dart, generator

From string I try to make a 2D array list to work as table. Until now below code works perfectly.
My problem start when I try to get old data from server. I try to modifiy the below code but I keep getting and error as shown below.

The actual data look like this **[01, 10, 04.11.2017, PN-DURUKAN, 18, B, 557.12, 20171014742, E, system, , AB40710000001680].**

If any data is not this format (example if I get a data as **[01, 10, 04.11.2017, ]** I need to put null value into rest and add into my List. How do I do that?

**The Error:**
E/flutter (10127): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(182)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (10127): RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in range 302..305, inclusive: 314
E/flutter (10127): #0      RangeError.checkValidRange (dart:core/errors.dart:325:9)

**The Code:**

```
Future<List<List<String>>> _makeTable(mText) async {
  var entries;
  entries = mText.split(":=:");
  if (entries.length < 2) {
    throw ArgumentError.value(mText, "text", "Invalid format");
  }
  int row = int.parse(entries[0]);
  int col = int.parse(entries[1]);

  //#####################################
  //TODO: I need to modify below if statement so I can set null value instead of throw an error
  //if (entries.length != 2 + row * col) {
    //throw ArgumentError.value(mText, "text", "Invalid format");
  //}

  // List<List<String>> returnArray;
  //returnArray = new List.generate(row, (i) => entries.sublist(2 + i * col, 2 + (i + 1) * col));
  //#####################################

  // ***** MODIFICATION SECTION *******:
  List<List<String>> returnArray;
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var _mValue;
    _mValue = entries.sublist(2 + i * col, 2 + (i + 1) * col);
    print("$_mValue");
  }
  return returnArray;
}
```

**Update the code:**

```
Future<List<List<String>>> _makeTable(mText) async {
  var entries;
  entries = mText.split(":=:");
  if (entries.length < 2) {
    throw ArgumentError.value(mText, "text", "Invalid format");
  }
  int row = int.parse(entries[0]);
  int col = int.parse(entries[1]);

  List<List<String>> returnArray = new List<List<String>>();
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var x = 2 + i * col;
    var y = 2 + (i + 1) * col;

    if (y <= entries.length) {
      returnArray.insert(i, entries.sublist(x, y));
    }
  }
  return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you access an index that is beyond the size of `entries`. Perhaps the `entries.sublist(...)` line.

Comment: thanks @GünterZöchbauer, I update the code. If data missing than I don't show. Expect db admin to correct the data. Thanks.